# Compiling Link Error: OpenArena

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, linker-errors, building

I am struggling my way through trying to build OpenArena 0.8.8 from source.

I am currently stuck on this build error message.

I already installed:
sudo apt-get install vorbis-tools-dbg & sudo apt-get install vorbis-tools

I'm pretty confident there is an easy fix, I'm just too inexperienced with this to know what it is. Thanks!

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/reimu/Desktop/openarena-engine-source-0.8.8'

Building openarena in build/release-linux-x86_64:
  PLATFORM: linux
  ARCH: x86_64
  VERSION: 1.36
  COMPILE_PLATFORM: linux
  COMPILE_ARCH: x86_64
  CC: cc

  CFLAGS:
    -Wall
    -fno-strict-aliasing
    -Wimplicit
    -Wstrict-prototypes
    -pipe
    -DUSE_ICON
    -DNO_GZIP
    -DUSE_LOCAL_HEADERS
    -DPRODUCT_VERSION="1.36"
    -MMD
    -DNDEBUG
    -O3
    -fomit-frame-pointer
    -funroll-loops
    -falign-loops=2
    -falign-jumps=2
    -falign-functions=2
    -fstrength-reduce
    -ffast-math

  CLIENT_CFLAGS:
    -D_GNU_SOURCE=1
    -D_REENTRANT
    -I/usr/include/SDL
    -DUSE_OPENAL
    -DUSE_OPENAL_DLOPEN
    -DUSE_CURL
    -DUSE_CURL_DLOPEN
    -DUSE_CODEC_VORBIS
    -Icode/SDL12/include
    -DUSE_MUMBLE
    -DUSE_VOIP
    -DFLOATING_POINT
    -DUSE_ALLOCA
    -Icode/libspeex/include

  SERVER_CFLAGS:
    -DUSE_VOIP

  LDFLAGS:

  LIBS:
    -ldl
    -lm

  CLIENT_LIBS:
    -lSDL
    -lGL
    -lvorbisfile
    -lvorbis
    -logg
    -lrt

  Output:
    build/release-linux-x86_64/oa_ded.x86_64
    build/release-linux-x86_64/openarena.x86_64

make[2]: Entering directory `/home/reimu/Desktop/openarena-engine-source-0.8.8'
make[2]: `build/release-linux-x86_64/oa_ded.x86_64' is up to date.
LD build/release-linux-x86_64/openarena.x86_64
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvorbisfile
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvorbis
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -logg
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [build/release-linux-x86_64/openarena.x86_64] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reimu/Desktop/openarena-engine-source-0.8.8'
make[1]: *** [targets] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reimu/Desktop/openarena-engine-source-0.8.8'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of the error message is

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvorbisfile
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvorbis
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -logg
```

This means that the linker cannot find `libogg`, `libvorbis` and `libvorbisfile`.

```
sudo apt-get install libogg-dev libvorbis-dev
```

should fix that.

It seems a bit odd at first that you get a linker error instead of a compiler error, but a cursory inspection of the Makefile leads me to believe that the first thing that is compiled (the server) does not actually use these libraries, and that they're included in the linker call to keep the build system simple. Since the linker is explicitly told to look for these libraries (which will be required for the client), it dutifully looks and complains when it doesn't find them.